# GNU parallel arguments

Tags: gnu-parallel

From the example

```
seq 1 100 | parallel -I @@ \ > 'mkdir top-@@;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-@@/sub-{}
```

How do `-X , @@, {}` work? Also, what will be the behavior when '1' or '.' is passed inside {}? Is /> used for redirection here?

I was trying to go through the tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P40akGWJ_gY&list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1&index=2 and reading through man parallel page. I am able to gather some basic knowledge but not exactly how to use it or as such.

Comment: Mark up code by selecting it with your mouse and then clicking the button labelled `{}` in the Formatting Toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic*.

Comment: Mark, I have highlighted the code now in Italic.

Comment: As you wish, but I suspect you'll get on better if you format it like the other 12 million questions on StackOverflow...

Comment: I believe the new formatting is what you mentioned Mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do the easy stuff first.

The backslash `(\)` is just telling the shell that the following line is a continuation of the current one, and the greater than sign (`>`) is the shell prompting for the continuation line. It is no different from typing:

```
echo \
hi
```

where you will actually see this:

```
echo \
> hi
hi
```

So, I am saying you can ignore `\>` and just run the command on a single line.

---

Next, the things in `{}`. These are described in the **GNU Parallel** manual page, but essentially:

- `{1}` refers to the first parameter
- `{2}` refers to the second parameter, and so on

Test this with the following where the column separator is set to a space but we use the parameters in the reverse order:

```
echo A B | parallel --colsep ' ' echo {2} {1}
B A
```

---

- `{.}` refers to a parameter, normally a filename, with its extension removed

Test this with:

```
echo fred.dat | parallel echo {.}
fred
```

---

Now let's come to the actual question, with the continuation line removed as described above and with everything on a single line:

```
seq 1 100 | parallel -I @@ 'mkdir top-@@;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-@@/sub-{}'
```

So, this is essentially running:

```
seq 1 100 | parallel -I @@ 'ANOTHER COMMAND'
```

Ole has used `@@` in place of `{}` in this command so that the substitutions used in the second, inner, parallel command don't get confused with each other. So, where you see `@@` you just need to replace it with the values from first `seq 1 100`.

The second parallel command is pretty much the same as the first one, but here Ole has used `X`. If you watch the video you link to, you will see that he previously shows you how it works. It actually passes *"as many parameters as possible"* to a command according to the system's `ARGMAX`. So, if you want 10,000 directories created, instead of this:

```
seq 1 10000 | parallel mkdir {}
```

which will start 10,000 separate processes, each one running `mkdir`, you will start one `mkdir` but with 10,000 parameters:

```
seq 1 10000 | parallel -X mkdir
```

That avoids the need to create 10,000 separate processes and speeds things up.

---

Let's now look at the outer `parallel` invocation and do a dry run to see what it would do, without actually doing anything:

```
seq 1 100 | parallel -k --dry-run -I @@ 'mkdir top-@@;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-@@/sub-{}'
```

**Output**

```
mkdir top-1;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-1/sub-{}
mkdir top-2;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-2/sub-{}
mkdir top-3;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-3/sub-{}
mkdir top-4;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-4/sub-{}
mkdir top-5;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-5/sub-{}
mkdir top-6;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-6/sub-{}
mkdir top-7;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-7/sub-{}
mkdir top-8;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-8/sub-{}
...
...
mkdir top-99;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-99/sub-{}
mkdir top-100;seq 1 100 | parallel -X mkdir top-100/sub-{}
```

So, now you can see it is going to start 100 processes, each of which will make a directory then start 100 further processes that will each create 100 subdirectories.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late acknowledgement. This one works good. But, I notice the following       1) echo fred.dat | parallel echo {.}                                                                                   When, I try to execute similar, I am getting the '.' and the <filename> in the reverse order as '.' <filename> respectively. Is there any reason that I get it in the reverse fashion?

Comment: When executing the command  - _echo A B | parallel --colsep ' ' echo {2} {1}_  , I am getting the output as  _2 1 A B_ . Is there any reason so?

Comment: Are you maybe running an older version? Try `parallel --version` and you should get something like `20190522` which is 2019 version.

Comment: It seems like I am running on a older version - 20180422. But, is this even quite old enough to work separately?

Comment: Maybe try adding `--gnu` to all commands, e.g. `parallel --gnu ...`  in case you have a `tollef` version.

Comment: You mean like _echo A B | parallel --gnu --colsep ' ' echo {2} {1}_ . This too gives me the same output as **2 1 A B**

Comment: I have no idea what's going wrong! Are you using `bash` as your shell or something odd like `zsh` or `fish`? Have you tried running `type parallel` to see if you are running the command you think you or on alias?